# How to create simple .NET application for co-worker that reads a local file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, security

I need to create a Windows application for a co-worker that will read and give some statistics on a local file. It seems a ClickOnce application is the way to go.

I've written the code, but am tearing my hair out trying:

- To set permissions for the app to read a local file
- To set up code signing or whatever is needed for the app to be allowed to run on my coworkers machine.

Some approaches I've looked into but haven't worked:

- Run Visual Studio as an administrator.
- Read from the `App_Data` directory. But where is this directory?
- Request permission to read local files. But how? Every "solution" presuming that we'll be installing from a web server.

I get a permissions error trying to read from user's home directory:

```
String soundBaseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\SaberSounds\";
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Have you considered using a scripting language instead?